# Maximum call Stack Exceeded after adding (load) in angular2 highchart

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am working on the angular2 highcharts. For the call back function i added (load) in the html like

```
 <chart [options]="options" (load)="FillTextCenter($event.context)"></chart>
```

After adding the load for the callback. I got the following error in my console window.

Maximum call stack exceeded error.

I tried to fix it.But i can't able to find.

Below codes are i tried but doesn't work.

Html file:

```
 <chart [options]="options" (load)="FillTextCenter($event.context)"></chart>
```

Ts file:

```
  options: Object;
FillTextCenter(chart) {
    this.options = chart;
}
```

Comment: Looks like the chart is recreated and load runs again and recreates chart and runs load and loops. Another option could be that the chart has looped references and when Angular tries to go inside it ends up trapped in a loop. I would bet on the first one. It looks like the angular2-highcharts wrapper issue. This wrapper has a github repo with issues tab enabled, so you could report the problem there. Please create a simple demo in Plunker for debugging. The official Angular2+ wrapper for Highcharts is a different module and it's here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

Comment: @Pandurengan G  check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47844198/3898339 answer it looks similar (load event)